# SQL insert query with group by

Tags: sql

trying to run the below query it wont work any ideas how to write it?

```
insert into daily_stats values (trunc(creation_timestamp), Message_Class, Channel, data_centre, Line_Of_Business, count(*))
    Select trunc(A.Creation_Timestamp), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business, Count(*) 
    From Payld_Data.Received_Messages A, Recon_Data.Reconciliation_Control B
    Where A.Conversation_Id = B.Conversation_Id
    group by Trunc(A.Creation_Timestamp), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business;
```

Comment: Step 1: Does the SELECT standalone produce the wanted result?

Comment: Step 2: Either VALUES or SELECT, not both.

Comment: (1) Sample data.  (2) Desired results.  (3) A tag for the database you are using.

Comment: "It won't work" Can you elaborate on this? What does the query say? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use values and select at same time.

Remove the VALUES and replace that with the column names you are inserting into the table (I updated it assuming column names so you may have to change them)

```
insert into daily_stats (creation_timestamp, Message_Class, Channel, data_centre, Line_Of_Business, ColumCount)
    Select trunc(A.Creation_Timestamp), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business, Count(*) 
    From Payld_Data.Received_Messages A, Recon_Data.Reconciliation_Control B
    Where A.Conversation_Id = B.Conversation_Id
    group by Trunc(A.Creation_Timestamp), A.Message_Class, A.Channel, A.Data_Centre, B.Line_Of_Business;
```

Comment: really appreciate the fast amazing response :)

Comment: @user9942230 NP, if it worked mark it as answer please.

Comment: how do I do this?